# My MainMenu.class in Android has this error that keeps saying one of my Strings is null using shared preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

The MainMenu class keeps throwing an error on a String that says its null and I am having the hardest time figuring this out.

It is throwing at NameText.setText()  of this MainMenu class.

I am going to feel stupid if this is something easy to fix lol

MainMenu.class :

```
package com.example.basicrecipes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainMenu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public static final String RecipeNamesPref = "RecipeNames";
    public static final String NamePref = "Name";
    public static final String DescriptionPref = "Description";
    public static final String PrefSteps = "How to Prepare";
    public static final String CuisinePref = "American";
    public static String SelectedRecipe = "SelectedRecipe";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.main_about_button);
        aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button newRecipe = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.main_new_button);
        newRecipe.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button exitApp = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.main_exit_button);
        exitApp.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button listRecipe = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.main_list_button);
        listRecipe.setOnClickListener(this);

        SharedPreferences selectedRecipe;
        selectedRecipe = getSharedPreferences(MainMenu.SelectedRecipe, RecipeEntry.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SelectedRecipe = selectedRecipe.getString(MainMenu.SelectedRecipe, "New Recipe");

        if ("New Recipe" != SelectedRecipe) {
            SharedPreferences thisRecipe = getSharedPreferences(SelectedRecipe + "_Detail", RecipeEntry.MODE_PRIVATE);
            EditText NameText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.name_new);
            NameText.setText(thisRecipe.getString(MainMenu.NamePref, ""));
            EditText DescriptionText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.description_new);
            DescriptionText.setText(thisRecipe.getString(MainMenu.DescriptionPref, ""));
            EditText TextSteps = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.new_steps);
            TextSteps.setText(thisRecipe.getString(MainMenu.PrefSteps, ""));
            Spinner CuisineSelect = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.cuisine_new);
            CuisineSelect.setSelection(thisRecipe.getInt(MainMenu.CuisinePref, 0));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View thisView) {
        switch (thisView.getId()) {
        case R.id.main_about_button:
            Intent showAbout = new Intent(this, About.class);
            startActivity(showAbout);
            break;
        case R.id.main_list_button:
            Intent doMenuClick = new Intent(this, RecipeList.class);
            startActivity(doMenuClick);
            break;
        case R.id.main_new_button:
            doMenuClick = new Intent(this, RecipeNew.class);
            startActivity(doMenuClick);
            break;
        case R.id.main_exit_button:
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            System.exit(1);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inf = getMenuInflater();
        inf.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        // menu.findItem(R.id.main_menu_search).setIntent(new Intent(this, SearchRecipe.class));
        menu.findItem(R.id.main_menu_options).setIntent(new Intent(this, Options.class));
        menu.findItem(R.id.main_menu_new).setIntent(new Intent(this, RecipeEntry.class));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem itm) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(itm);
        Intent menuIntent = itm.getIntent();
        if (menuIntent != null)
            startActivity(menuIntent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check whether `NameText` is null after initialization?

Comment: Does an `EditText` with id `name_new` exist in your layout file?

Comment: make sure you have `EditText` with id `name_new` in `main` layout file.

Comment: can you write the exact error you are getting

Comment: yep, need crash log,

Comment: how do I post my log?

Comment: 02-25 01:11:07.882: E/AndroidRuntime(17796): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 01:11:07.882: E/AndroidRuntime(17796): Process: com.example.basicrecipes, PID: 17796
02-25 01:11:07.882: E/AndroidRuntime(17796): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.basicrecipes/com.example.basicrecipes.MainMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Can you post your xml layout? And you can edit your question and add additional details.

Comment: Set a break point here `NameText.setText(thisRecipe.getString(MainMenu.NamePref, ""));` and make sure `NameText` is not null.

Comment: Replace `this.findViewById()` with `findViewById()`.

Comment: His problems is not with the UI or XML.

Problem lays with his SharedPreferences. 

`SharedPreferences thisRecipe = getSharedPreferences(SelectedRecipe + "_Detail", RecipeEntry.MODE_PRIVATE);`

This is the problem, there is no such SharedPreferences found with the given key! 

NPE is thrown because `thisRecipe` is null! Please check how you are getting your shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies here :

```
if ("New Recipe" != SelectedRecipe) {
```

Comparing string like this is only comparing the `Object` type, not the String value itself.

I'm making a wild guess that the `SharedPreferences` **SelectedRecipe_Detail** does not exist.

Hence, NPE is thrown when you are trying to `getString()` from it.

Solution :

Do your checking as below :

```
if(!"New Recipe".equals(SelectedRecipe)) {
```

Comment: 02-25 01:35:53.652: E/AndroidRuntime(18673): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
02-25 01:35:53.652: E/AndroidRuntime(18673):  at com.example.basicrecipes.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:50)

Comment: 02-25 01:48:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(20988):  at com.example.basicrecipes.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:50)
02-25 01:48:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(20988):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
02-25 01:48:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(20988):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
02-25 01:48:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(20988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2310)
02-25 01:48:15.472: E/AndroidRuntime(20988):  ... 10 more

Comment: I close the app, reopen it and when the splash screen is done loading to enter the main menu... it crashes???

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem 
You are using SelectedRecipe  as constant

```
public static String SelectedRecipe = "SelectedRecipe";
```

and then you are updating its value in

```
   SelectedRecipe = selectedRecipe.getString(MainMenu.SelectedRecipe, "New Recipe");
```

then you are using it again which makes it wrong

```
    SharedPreferences thisRecipe = getSharedPreferences(SelectedRecipe + "_Detail", RecipeEntry.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Change below code

```
       String SelectedRecipe = selectedRecipe.getString(MainMenu.SelectedRecipe, "New Recipe");

        if ("New Recipe" != SelectedRecipe) {

to 

        String retSelectedRecipe = selectedRecipe.getString(MainMenu.SelectedRecipe, "New Recipe");

        if (!"New Recipe".equals(retSelectedRecipe) ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the problem is.

I got this book:
[The Complete Idiots Guide to Android App Development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuuC6.jpg)

This was released in 2011 and I am pretty sure things have changed since then.
I recommend that you DO NOT GET THIS BOOK!!! WARNING!!! 
This Book is VERY POORLY MADE!!!

Through out the whole book the variables change and things get switch around and not just that, he does not specify a lot of important detail about anything. It is very Half Assed!!!